# Call Action on DropDownListFor on select in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I have two dropdoenlistfor control for Country & City.So I want to bind city drop-down list on basis of selected country. How can I achieve this ?

here is my code

AirportController.cs

```
    // GET: Airport/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<City> lstCity = new DACity().GetListAll();
        ViewBag.City = lstCity;

        List<Country> lstCountry = new DACountry().GetListAll();
        ViewBag.Country = lstCountry;

        return View();
    }
```

Create.cshtml

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Country, "CountryID", "CountryName"), "--select--", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div> 


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityID, new SelectList(ViewBag.City, "CityID", "CityName"), "--select--", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: use `ajax` to pull the data.

Comment: use jquery to get city's data.. use this link for help.. http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1145/mvc-dropdownlistfor-fill-on-selection-change-of-another-dropdown

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for implementing cascading dropdownlists

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding a client-side change event to the country dropdown? Based on the selection made, you can make an AJAX call to a secondary controller method which will then return you a list of cities to populate into the dropdown.

You might also want to consider the POST so that if any errors are encountered, you will load the city information before returning the View, just ensures that the state of the model is preserved should any server-side validation fail.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the Onchange event of dropdownlistfor and pass the selected value of dropdownlistfor to the handler function.

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Country, "CountryID", "CountryName"), "--select--", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "ChangeCityValues(this.value)" } })`

Inside the function do an ajax post to controller to change the model's datasource for city and pass the value to it

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("ChangeCitySource", "YourControllerName")',
    data: JSON.stringify({ countryId: CountryIdValueReceivedfromDropdown }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        if (true) {
            Update city dropdown
        }
        else {
            No action
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        return "error";
    }
});
```

In `YourControllerName` Controller :

```
public JsonResult ChangeCitySource( string countryId)
{
    // Update city source here and return some result to ajax post
}
```